# Backward slice generation for a java file

Tags: java, program-slicing

I have a java file and I want to get all the lines that have impact on result of a specific line (Backward Slice Generation). I know the solution but is there any java code to do that?

as an example cosider the following code:

```
System.out.println("Start")
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(10);
int n = 0;
if(i<8)
{
    n = 1;
    System.out.println("In if");
}
int j = n * i;
```

I need a code that find the following lines when I run it for line 10:

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(10);
int n = 0;
if(i<8)
{
    n = 1;
}
int j = n * i;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are more academic papers discussing the theoretical approach than there are actual implementations. (Especially in Java)

You could try one of the following options:

**Analyzing singlethreaded programs:**

**Java Slicer** from hammacher(*@github*). As far as I remember, it gives you a java bytecode slice after you have created a trace out of your program.

Also look at **IBM Wala Slicer**.

**Analyzing multithreaded programs:**

The problem is that complexity rises especially when analyzing multithreaded programs. 
I think the only one currently supporting this is the [Indus](http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu/) project. They also provide an eclipse plugin, called **Kaveri**, but you had to use it with Eclipse 3.1.2

However, your code has to be compliant with **Java 2(J2SE 1.4.2)**. see [Java Support](http://projects.cis.ksu.edu/gf/project/indus/forum/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=32228&action=ForumBrowse&forum_id=34)